# How are arrays handled in memory?

Tags: c#, .net

Given that an array is allocated a fixed area of memory, it makes complete sense that the length of the array is immutable.

Let's say I have Array[10] - this will allocate 10 slots of adjacent memory right? And it is because these slots are adjacent and at predetermined locations, indexed based lookups are quick.

But what if I'm putting complex types into my array, of uneven sizes. The actual objects in the array might be of the same type, but the data they hold can differ vastly in size.

How does .Net handle this? I would imagine it allocates non sequential memory to store the actual data in the objects but I would like an authoritative answer on this. For example - does it only use non sequential memory if the object exceeds a certain size? What if the object is constantly changing in size, will it keep trying to optimize a storage location?

Consider this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass[] PotentiallyHugeNestedStructure
}
```

Now if I have an array of myclass and at runtime start allocating to sub arrays and sub arrays. I can end up with a vast collection of jagged arrays.

So how does .net handle this, in memory?

Comment: *The actual objects in the array* ?! No, the array holds references to the objects memory location (In the managed heap) and not the objects themselves !

Comment: @user3185569, so they're really just a sequential linked list?

Comment: `The actual objects in the array might be of the same type, but the data they hold can differ vastly in size` Even if the data differs the storage allocated per index is the same (int 4 bytes) as long as that allocated memory can hold the value stored for that block

Comment: if I had to guess, I would say that a jagged arrays items are stored sequentially and what is stored is a reference to the actual object. I have no idea really, I am interested in the answer

Comment: Array elements are _always_ fixed size. If they are reference types, then the elements themselves are just references (32 bits on x86, 64 bits on x64, etc.). If they are value types, then each value is always the same size, and so is each array element.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes same point, you explained it better (y). So in his example the size of each index should be the total size of MyClass object

Comment: @Sherlock: no. In his example `MyClass` is a reference type, and so each array element is the size of a reference on that platform (again, 32 bits on x86, 64 bits on x64, etc.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In arrays of reference types, each element in the array holds a reference that points to an object in the managed heap.

So in the scope of the size of the array itself (as you specified) there is no disadvantage of having an array of objects over an array of primitive types (other than the overhead of creating objects themselves that the array elements **reference** which has nothing to do with the size of the array in memory).

In scope of accessing elements by index, there is no difference as both are accessed by index. There is for sure a overhead for retrieving the object by reference from the heap, but it is extremely fast (Since the reference is usually a number that represents an offset to a memory location).

The below image demonstrates arrays holding reference types vs arrays holding value types:

[image]

Image from : CLR Via C# by Jeffrey Richter

`myControls` is an array of objects, so each element holds either Null (by default) or a reference to an object (4 bytes for 32-bit systems and 8 bytes for 64-bit systems).

**Side Note:** The overhead specified in the picture contains information about the array:

- Dimension
- The lower bound of each dimension (0 is most cases)
- The length of the array.

Comment: _"So there is absolutely no disadvantage of having an array of objects over an array of primitive types. You can access any object in the list through the index in a very fast manner"_ -- for a variety of reasons, this statement is dangerously incorrect. There are many scenarios where an array of value types significantly outperforms an array of reference types. One of the biggest factors is memory locality and its effect on caching but there are other issues as well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think what I wrote was not clear enough. I was mentioning that as a reply to what the OP said. He though an array of objects takes more size in memory than a primitive types array which is not necessary true. It might also be the other way around, as some values types needs more memory that a reference. I hope the edit is now clear.

Comment: Please provide an example of a value type that, doing the same effective job as an equivalent reference type, uses _more_ memory than that equivalent reference type.

Comment: @PeterDuniho If you have 3 objects in memory with multiple fields, one of which is a `decimal` field. And you needed to pass those 3 fields to a method. Let's forget design decisions now. Passing an array referencing the three objects consumes less memory (Size of the Array itself) than passing a array containing the three decimal fields. Right ?

Comment: Wrong. Passing an array costs just a single reference: the reference to the array object, which is a reference type. The total memory consumption for an array of reference types would be the three array elements **plus** the size of the three objects, while for an array of value types it would just be the size of the three objects (because they are contained within the array itself instead of being separate objects on the heap).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm talking about an example where the objects are already in memory. The Size of the array containing N references is less than the size of the array containing N decimal numbers. I'm not talking about the size of the objects themselves in memory. Remember, we're still talking in the scope of the SO's question, he thought that objects being themselves stored in the array and so he thought the size of the array(itself) referencing objects is Larger that primitive types array (which is not always the case). I never said using objects is more memory efficient than primitive types!

Comment: Ignoring the size of the objects in the heap makes no sense. That's where the actual data is stored. The array itself is pointless without them. In any case, I was responding to your _comment_, in which you wrote _"**Passing** an array referencing the three objects consumes less memory (Size of the Array itself) than **passing** a array containing the three decimal fields"_. I.e. your comment is specifically discussing what happens when the array is **passed**, and in that case the array type doesn't matter; a single reference is passed, always, no matter what type the array stores.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It was obvious I didn't mean the cost of passing the array, in both cases it is a single references and that's just very obvious. But the cost of declaring and assigning that array. Taking into consideration you already have these N objects in memory, then creating an array of N References to existing objects vs creating an array of N decimals. In the first case the array size allocated in memory is less. That's my point.

Comment: _"in both cases it is a single references and that's just very obvious"_ -- it should be obvious. But your other comments mischaracterize the nature of arrays, and in any case you were very explicit in using the word **passing**, and so whatever one might hope is obvious, your statement was that of someone to whom it was very much not obvious.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right I used the wrong words. At the end, we do agree that each one was talking about a different correct point.